# opennlp.tools.postag.POSTaggerME.train() java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream, opennlp, pos-tagger

There are same problem! I get **InputSteram = null**, I used IntelliJ IDEA, OpenNLP 1.9.1. on Ubuntu 18.04

```
    public void makeDataTrainingModel() {
    model = null;
    System.out.println("POS model started");
    //InputStream dataIn = null;
    InputStreamFactory dataIn = null;
    try {
        dataIn = new InputStreamFactory() {
            public InputStream createInputStream() throws IOException {
                return NLPClassifier.class.getResourceAsStream("/home/int/src          
    /main/resources/en-pos.txt");
            }
        };
        //I get null pointer here in dataIn
        ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream((InputStreamFactory) , "UTF-8");
        ObjectStream<POSSample> sampleStream = new WordTagSampleStream(lineStream);
     **//This train part IS NOT WORK ?**
        model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, TrainingParameters.defaultParams(), null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Failed to read or parse training data, training failed
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (dataIn != null) {
           
            System.out.println("InputStreamFactory was not created!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("POS model done...");
    System.out.println("Success generate model...");
    //write Data model
    OutputStream modelOut = null;
    try {
        String currentDir = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(currentDir + "//src//main//resources//example-bad-model.dat"));


        model.serialize(modelOut);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Failed to save model
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (modelOut != null) {
            try {
                modelOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Failed to correctly save model.
                // Written model might be invalid.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Model generated and treated successfully...");
}
```

I get null pointer in inputStream and Error...
InputStreamFactory was not created!

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
    at     
    opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream.reset(PlainTextByLineStream.java:57)
    at opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream.<init>   
    (PlainTextByLineStream.java:48)
    at opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream.<init>    
   (PlainTextByLineStream.java:39)

   at NLPClassifier.makeDataTrainingModel(NLPClassifier.java:98)
   at NlpProductClassifier.main(NlpProductClassifier.java:39)
```

Data looks like this:
profit_profit shell_environment 384912_CD bucks_currency 
salary_profit finger_body 913964_CD usd_currency 
profit_profit faith_law 3726_CD rur_currency 
profit_profit game_entertainment 897444_CD dollar_currency
 
got_buy gift_jewelery 534841_CD rub_currency 
 
**Why the thread does not open and it throw an exception?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getResourceAsStream` returns `null`, it means that the resource wasn't found.

You should check for `null` and do something else, such as throwing an exception (`IOException` or `FileNotFoundException` in this case, since `IOException` and subclasses are allowed by the `throws` declaration) - you shouldn't let it pass the `null` to the rest of your code.

`NLPClassifier.class.getResourceAsStream("/home/int/src/main/resources/en-pos.txt")` won't work, because resources have the same structure as Java packages, except that dots are replaced with slashes. It's not a path in the file system.

Change it to: `getResourceAsStream("/en-pos.txt")` (because your file is at the root of the package hierarchy)

Comment: Thanks @erwin-bolwidt, for modifications, i change code as your advise! I find another problem in OpenNLP)

Answer (score 0):

I change my code, as Erwin Bolwidt say:

```
    /** I commented this part
    return NLPClassifier.class.getResourceAsStream("/home/interceptor/src/main/resources/en-pos.txt");
    */
    /**
     Add this location of my resoures:
     /Project/src/main/resources
    */
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("en-pos.txt");
```

After that, i found  [Apache OpenNLP: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be cast to opennlp.tools.util.InputStreamFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699913/apache-opennlp-java-io-fileinputstream-cannot-be-cast-to-opennlp-tools-util-inp/41700051), with a similar problem, but with other methods. @schrieveslaach says

> You need an instance of InputStreamFactory which will retrieve your InputStream. Additionally, **TokenNameFinderFactory must not be null !** like this **posFactory -  must not be null!**

```
    /**
     *  Factory must not be a null. Add posModel.getFactory()
     *  model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, TrainingParameters.defaultParams(), null);
     */
     model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, TrainingParameters.defaultParams(), posModel.getFactory());
```

Full code of project in repo  https://github.com/AlexTitovWork/NLPclassifier